# Powershell ISE function outputting double characters before the expected output

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell ISE function that is returning any char/strings i put into it before as well as in the expected output of the string.

EDIT: Even though this specific example could be solved with a regex that is not the point the sample data in the for loop as it is getting sorted and placed in a string and the error of the extra chars created make it impossible to correctly format the output.  The sample code below is a simplified version that displays the issue but ultimately it will create a large variance of chars/strings added to variables depending on different situations that requires a clean run of the function without work arounds.

I have tried changing the code around but for some reason it always returns the same type of bug.

```
Function Get-structure{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param (
        [string]$inut
    )
    $output=""
    $DelimListItem=$inut.Split("`r`n")
    for($i=1;$i -lt $DelimListItem.count;$i++){
        $output=$output+$DelimListItem[$i]+"!"
    }
    return $output
}

$testdata="APP~MEM~Error
Server~00:14~99.54~0~0~0
Server~00:29~99.48~0~0~1"

Get-structure -inut $testdata
```

Output I get:

```
!Server~00:14~99.54~0~0~0!!Server~00:29~99.48~0~0~1!
```

Expected output:

```
Server~00:14~99.54~0~0~0!Server~00:29~99.48~0~0~1!
```

Comment: I'm getting the expected output on PowerShell v5.1 with your code unchanged

Comment: It appears to run fine in regular powershell but powershell ise is where it gives the unexpected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easier with the `-replace` operator.

```
Function Get-structure{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param (
        [string]$inut
    )
    $inut -replace "(\r?\n)|$","!"
}
```

**Output:**

```
$testdata="APP~MEM~Error
Server~00:14~99.54~0~0~0
Server~00:29~99.48~0~0~1"

Get-structure -inut $testdata

APP~MEM~Error!Server~00:14~99.54~0~0~0!Server~00:29~99.48~0~0~1!
```

**Explanation:**

- `-replace` is the regex replace operator. Its first input (data between first pair of quotes) is a regex pattern. The second input (data between the second set of quotes) is the replacement string, which can be omitted if you just want matched strings removed.
- `(\r?\n)|$` is the regex pattern, which will replace CRLF or LF or the end of the string. In our case, the replacement is a `!`.

  - `\r?` matches zero or one carriage return. Depending on how `$testdata` is created, there may or may not be a CR character.
  - `\n` matches one newline character
  - `|` is an OR mechanism in regex
  - `$` is the end of the string

The problem with the **.Split("`r`n")** method is that it is ignoring `n. It splits at `r and then `n is put on a line by itself. It results in the following, which means those empty lines get joined with a `!` as well. The console doesn't seem to have this behavior, but ISE does.

```
> $testdata.split("`r`n")
APP~MEM~Error

Server~00:14~99.54~0~0~0

Server~00:29~99.48~0~0~1
```

If you wanted your code structure to remain the same, you could replace `.Split()` with the `-split` operator instead. ISE and the console treat that operator equally in this case. See below for using `-split`.

```
Function Get-structure{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param (
        [string]$inut
    )
    $DelimListItem=$inut -split "\r?\n"
    $output = ($DelimListItem | Select-Object -Skip 1) -join "!"
    "{0}!" -f $output
}


$testdata="APP~MEM~Error
Server~00:14~99.54~0~0~0
Server~00:29~99.48~0~0~1"

Get-structure -inut $testdata

Server~00:14~99.54~0~0~0!Server~00:29~99.48~0~0~1!
```

Comment: it always surprises me when folks fail to look at their data _as it exists in each step_. [*grin*] your demo of the source of the problem - the output of the `.Split()` - is right on-point ... [*grin*]

Comment: Can't use regex i'm not actually replacing the carriage return with an ! it just happens the sample defacto does that.

Comment: @Deraxel Can you explain what your requirements are in detail? A -replace can be variable/dynamic. If we use `.split()` vs. -replace within this same context, you would have the same complaint. If you need to split the items, then just use `-split` instead. It doesn't have the bug.

Comment: @Deraxel, I added the `-split` alternative to the bottom of the post. I removed the for loop because it is not necessary when you want to just skip an item in a list.

Comment: @AdminOfThings That's it! This thing has been screwing with me for the past 2 days thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-join` parameter to join different string and seperate them with specific character or string.

```
Function Get-structure{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param (
        [string]$inut
    )
    $output=""
    $DelimListItem=$inut.Split("`r`n")
    $output = $DelimListItem -join "!"
    $output += "!"
    return $output
}
```

`$output += "!"` to add the last (!) to the string

Comment: Still doubling the characters
And the new list will be created line by line depending on a lot of if/then variables with new text.  Essentially multiple different types of sentences will be outputted depending on the data in each line of the $DelimListItem.